# Publish coverage result from gitlab project

Tags: gitlab

On a project at gitlab.com I run tests and coverage analysis. I'd like to publish the results (an HTML file). I read [this](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/11/03/publish-code-coverage-report-with-gitlab-pages/) page and I have an entry in the .gitlab.yml file to publish the results:

```
pages:
  stage: publish
  dependencies:
    - run-test-coverage
  script:
    - mv _build/test public/
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  when: always
```

The job passes, but I can't find where this report is published. I see the generated file in artifacts, but that's not user-friendly, because gitlab tells me that "*The source could not be displayed because it is stored as a job artifact. You can download it instead.*" I'm using gitlab-ce from dockerhub (if it matters).

Answer (score 1):

If it's an internal or private project it wont work unless you have GitLab Pages Access controls enabled: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#browsing-artifacts

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but if you look further down on the page you're linking to, you'll see this:

> You also need to rename the directory from coverage/ to public/ because this is the directory that GitLab Pages expects to find static website in.

There's a separate stage defined to publish the results in the example:

```
pages:
  stage: deploy
  dependencies:
    - rspec
  script:
    - mv coverage/ public/
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
    expire_in: 30 days
  only:
    - master
```

Comment: GitLab Pages works (or used to work the last time I checked) only with public projects, so we couldn't use it..

Comment: Ah, I see. I guess a clunky way of dealing with that then is to push the files to an internal site.

Or use the Gitlab API to publish it on the project's wiki. We are doing that for some other build related bits of info.

Answer (score 0):

GitLab Pages does not only work for public projects. In fact, project visibility does not matter at all:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/introduction.html#can-i-use-gitlab-pages-if-my-project-is-private

Therefore, simply moving your html file to public within your `.gitlab-ci.yml` would be enough to publish the site:

```
pages:
  script:
  - mv coverage public
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```

Comment: I've tried this suggestion, but in a private project on an internal Gitlab instance, it still displayed _The source could not be displayed because it is stored as a job artifact. You can download it instead_